# Is MAC required for Xamarin VisualStudio IOS Development?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I started working on mobile Apps using Xamarin VisualStudio Cross-platform.
I am able to debug on android and see output, but when I try to debug CrossPlatform.iOS (Set as StartUp Project) using iphone device (please note, I have attached Iphone4), its asking **mac name or IP**. When I input IP, it then ask me for remote login.

Please see below screen shots. Any thought? Sorry for simple question, I just started Mobile development using Xamarin

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just like you can't build Windows applications without a Windows machine, you can't build native iOS applications without a Mac Machine. Xamarin uses the XCode tool chain to build your application. Unfortunately Apple doesn't make XCode for Windows :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes. A Mac is always required. This is also stated in the [requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/) by Xamarin.

The compilation of iOS apps has to be done on a physical Mac machine. Xamarin has created a lot of tools and applications so you can do all of the development on your Windows machine, but under the hood your code will still be send over to a Mac and return to you with the results.

You can either buy a Mac (Mini is probably the cheapest option) or sign up for a service like [Macincloud.com](http://macincloud.com).